# Arrays search method confusion

Tags: java, collections

I am confused about [`Arrays.binarySearch(Object[], Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-).

```
public class SearchObjArray {

    public  static void main(String[] args){

        String[] sa = {"one","two","three","four"};

        Arrays.sort(sa);

        for(String s : sa ){
            System.out.println(s + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n one = " + Arrays.binarySearch(sa,"thro"));
}
}
```

When the program is run, it returns position `-4`. I was reading in the book, it states that, insertion point is represented as `(-(insertionPoint)-1)`. Why it is like this? I am not able to grasp this point.

Comment: my question is both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the array.

```
{"one","two","three","four"}
```

sorted is

```
{"four", "one", "three", "two"}
```

and `throw` comes after `three`. So the insertion point would be `3`. The result thus is

```
(-(insertionPoint) -1) =
(-(3)              -1) =
-4
```